# How to get Table Of Content in document view for Xcode 6.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, documentation, tableofcontents

After updating Xcode to 6.2, the table of content in document viewer is missing for most of the UI classes references. Is any one else experiencing this issue?  Is there any way to show the table of content in document viewer just like what it used to be?

[image]

Comment: I have exactly the same issue

Comment: I also have this problem in Xcode 6.2.0, and the documentation sets HAVE been downloaded. This is one of four versions of Xcode I have installed under Yosemite (others are 5.1.1, 6.1.1, and 6.3.0). All show the docs for that version of Xcode and that version of iOS are installed, yet the other three Xcode's DO show the TOC. I'd like to have this working in all four Xcode installs; any suggestion how to achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same he same issue - table of contents pane was blank.

However, when I checked Preferences / Downloads, I saw that the Documentation objects iOS 8.2, OS X 10.10 and XCode 6.2 were all available but **not yet downloaded**, despite the fact that the "Check for and install updates automatically" was checked.

Once I had manually selected and finished downloaded iOS 8.2 documentation, the table of contents pane was appearing normally again.

Comment: I have seen those documents not download under preferences / Downloads before.  But I always assume the documents are accessible online so I never bother to download them.  Thanks for pointing it out.  Will give it a try.

Comment: It is working now after I follow your suggestion to download those documents.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: yes, when they're showing you documentation, it's hard to deduce the fact that you're missing the documentation - thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could always install Dash. It's a third party tool that gives a great interface to searching locally downloaded documentation (including iOS docs). Assuming you've downloaded the 8.2 documentation already, it should automatically detect it on installation. It's free and I'd highly recommend it.

[App Store Link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dash/id458034879?ls=1&mt=12)

Comment: Dash is a awesome tool, but too many waiting in the free version.

Answer (score 1):

There is a play button next to menu button to show up the main menu of all available documents.

[image]

This is a when I clicked to the button:
[image]

To download documents in XCode: Goto 'Downloads' section in XCode Preference panel.

[image]

Comment: thanks.  I added a screenshot of what I now typically see in document viewer.  The table of content is blank.

Comment: If you have document available, you have to click to the triangle next to menu button to show the menu. If you don't have documents available, you have to download it. See my 2nd photo

Comment: That's not the solution to his problem. I have the same issue.

Comment: Have you downloaded contents? When you clicked to the button, was the triangle change the direction?

Comment: The triangle icon shows/hides the document navigator, not the table of contents.  In your 1st screenshot, it looks like you're having the same issue— your table of contents icon is highlighted but the ToC pane is blank.  It is working for you in your 2nd screenshot, however, visible to the right of the navigator (the pane that starts with the text _“Core Data Constants Re…”_).  **When in doubt, hold your cursor still for a second over any button in macOS and it'll show you a tooltip describing its function.**