# How to show documentation outline in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, documentation

I'm learning how to use Xcode and have a question.

I'm quite often using the documentation, but I have found that is easier to use it in the web browser than in XCode, because in XCode I don't see the frame on the left. Outline?

[image: I mean this on the left - "Tasks, Revision History..."]

When I double click sth with option key then I just get the center part:

[image: No content on the left]

I remember that few days ago I had the same in Xcode, where did it go? What should I do?

Comment: have you tried `option+click` on a class name?

Comment: yes, option+click one time gives me small info, option + double click opens documentation window but without usefull outline on the left. Sometimes when i click on the other class name in documentation it shows this for about half a second but then it disapear...

Comment: I have this same issue on two fresh installs of Xcode 6 on two different machines.  I am new to iOS dev and that outline seems incredibly useful.  I would like to add it.

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111817/how-to-get-table-of-content-in-document-view-for-xcode-6-2

so this looks like a dup.